# html5 dropdown list with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to show a dropdown list of 250 countries in a html page. I can do it easily do it by below

```
<select id="country" name="country">
<option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="2">Albania</option>
.....
<option value="250">Canary Islands</option>
</select>
```

I have to use 5 times the same list in a html page. so, how can i reduce repeat work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's clone to clone the element: http://api.jquery.com/clone/

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
  $("body").append($("#country").clone(false).prop("id", "country"+i));
}
```

This will clone the country dropdown 5 times, changing the ID property of each to make it unique, then append it to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option in plain ol' JavaScript:

```
var cloneList = function(){
 return this.cloneNode();
}.bind(document.getElementById('country'));

var count = 5;
while(count--) document.body.appendChild(cloneList()).id = 'country' + count;
```

You can reuse the cloneList function whenever you need it.